# Can I use a colon and a question mark at the same time?

Tags: punctuation, questions, colons, question-mark

What punctuation should I use with a monologue that starts out with a rhetorical question and continues with an example?

Have you ever wondered how much time we spend in situations like this one: [insert lengthy story]

or

Have you ever wondered how much time we spend in situations like this one?: [insert lengthy story]

or

Have you ever wondered how much time we spend in situations like this one? [insert lengthy story]

Comment: I thought it might be different because that query talks about a single item or a list of items after a question, rather than a question followed by a narrative of several complete sentences.

Comment: The title is essentially the same, and answers there address general situations.

Answer (score 0):

Rhetorical or not, you are still asking a question. Keep the question mark, and strike the colon. In this instance, they are mutually exclusive.